# Trouble parsing for specific things like created_at, favorite_count, etc using tweepy

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy, python-3.7

I'm currently using Twitter API to search for tweets using tweepy, and I'm trying to parse for specific parts of a tweet like created_at, favorites, retweets, user id, id, and text of the tweet, but when I run my code, nothing happens?

So far I've been able to obtain the data from twitter and put it in json format, I have a text file with that data, so when I call it, it's supposed to iterate through that file and pull the specific items for each tweet.

Here is the code for what i'm trying to attempt, parsing wise.

```
filename = "clipboard2.txt"
jsonfile = open(filename, "r")
for line in jsonfile:
try:
    rows = json.loads(line.strip())
    if 'text' in rows:  # only messages contains 'text' field is a tweet
        print("rows"['id'])  # This is the tweet's id
        print(["rows"]['created_at'])  # when the tweet posted
        print(rows["rows"]['text']) # content of the tweet
        print(rows["rows"]['retweet_count'])
        print(rows["rows"]['favorite_count'])
        print["rows"]["user-id"]  # id of the user who posted the tweet
        print(rows["rows"]['user']['name'])  # name of the user, e.g. "Wei Xu"
        print(rows["rows"]['user']['screen_name'])
except:
    continue
```

My text file/code looks like this: [Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAhC7.jpg)

It seems like there's no error, since it runs with no errors, but I'm not too sure how to handle the data. The way that I'm thinking is that I have "rows" in quotations because that's the first line of the json file and everything following it is stored in an array, correct? So what I want is it to iterate over each part of the array with the items that I have and print out every element of the tweet that has those.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

## IMPORT NECESSARY PACKAGES

```
from tweet_parser.tweet import Tweet
from tweet_parser.tweet_parser_errors import NotATweetError
```

## PARSE

```
filename = "tweet_data.txt"
jsonfile = open(filename, "r")
for line in jsonfile:    
    try:
        if not line.strip(): continue # skips the empty lines, if any
        tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
        tweet = Tweet(tweet_dict)
    except:
        pass
    if tweet.text != None:
        print(tweet.id)  # This is the tweet's id
        print(tweet.created_at_datetime)  # when the tweet posted
        print(tweet.text) # content of the tweet
        print(tweet.retweet_count)
        print(tweet.favorite_count)
        print(tweet.user_id)
        print(tweet.screen_name)
```